# When we change in database is it neccessary to create edmx file everytime, cant we update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-4, edmx

When we make changes in database , is there any requirement to change Edmx also , means we have to delete existing edmx file and again i have to create edmx file and add all the tables ones again

Comment: No..they automatically gets refreshed..

Answer (score 0):

You can update it. Following are the steps:

1. Open your edmx by double clicking on it.
2. Right Click-> Update Model From Database
3. Choose Sensitivity of connection string click next
4. Select your changes and click Finish.

This should do it.